# add button to switch browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the top of my website pages, I like to recommend to view my site with chrome and suggest to change browser add a button that when the user click it, one of the 2 options will happen:

1. If the chrome is already installed -> the page will be opened on the chrome (if the user's default browser isn't chrome).
2. If the chrome isn't installed -> popup message that says: "chrome hasn't been installed yet. For free download:link"

I assume that these two functions are already exist but I don't even know where to start searching....

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Can't get those(installed s/w) becoz of security purpose.

Comment: Instead you can simply detect the browser the user is using and suggest to use Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect what applications are installed on a computer using client side JavaScript (or any information that it sent to the server).

A webpage cannot trigger the loading on an arbitrary application on the client.

So no, neither of this functions exist and they cannot be written.